# Things to visit in West Sussex, Great Britain

Tags: uk, planning, architecture, history

I'm planning a trip to Great Britain for entertainment purposes, and as a side effect I can visit **West Sussex** region at the end of May. I'm interested in historic monuments and landscapes.

What are the most interesting things to see in that area, beside the sea?

I saw some medieval castles, but they seem too far from **Wiston**, the place where I have accommodation.

[Edit]
I plan to travel with a rented car but I only have few hours until afternoon, when some events I participate are scheduled.

I searched for places to visit in that region and beside sea (that can be reached quickly from Winston and fulfill a personal wish):

- Buchan Country Park (40km - that is 2 hours required to visit a park, not sure if is worth the time).
- Arundel Castle (22 km).
- Bodiam Castle (88 km, a bit too far)

I haven't been to England before I do not know what to expect, what's interesting and worth visiting in countryside. Usually I ask friends that traveled before, but this time it seems that I am the pioneer.

I plan to stay in London after, for a few days, but some friends have already been there, so the list of things to visit/do is easier to make.

Comment: Did you search online? You are supposed to do your own homework before asking here. One look at google maps showed me it is a region with loads of things to do. To give you any useful information you need to tell us more about yourself, like what transport you will be using and how far is too far.

Comment: Gatwick airport

Comment: Is there something interesting to visit, beside the terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that list and the fact that you will have a car I would sugest to go to Arundal castle, be there the moment it opens, so you have a fair time. Old and big castle, worth visiting.
Not all of it is old, but enough to make it worth your time.

If you are an early riser, you can visit the sea before the castle.

And for a park, try the [Weald and Dowland Open Air museum](http://www.wealddown.co.uk/) (if open at the time of year you are there.) Not too big, not too far and very nice to visit, even when you have less time. Good historic buildings in a vilage set-up.
[image: Photo of the village in the Weald and Downland museum, as seen from a hill]
*The Weald and Downland Open Air Museum*
by Anguskirk under CC BY-NC-ND 2.0 licence (creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/2.0/) via flic.kr/p/dhVVnL

If you want a certain kind of village to visit, you can use an images search or use a map site where you can also see the streets as if you are walking there. Street view or whatever it is called in other sites and you get a fair idea of what a village looks like.
The maps will likely give you several options near your location as well as several you will pass through on your way to and from your chosen attractions.

Having played around a bit with street view, I would suggest Storrington, the area around the White Horse, google maps gives North Street for the address.
[image: The White Horse, Storrington]
*The White Horse, Storrington*
 © Copyright David960 and licensed for reuse under this Creative Commons Licence.
[Full credits and links to other content in this link.](http://www.geograph.org.uk/reuse.php?id=4392099)

Storrington is on the A283, going west from Wiston just beyond Washington where you might want to stop just for the name.

Comment: Speaking of historic buildings in a village set-up, aren't there any villages that are not so modern and look like those from Sherlock Holmes movies?

Comment: I bet that half the villages in the area will look like what you search for, at least in the older parts, but I am not familiar enough with the region.